# How to add labels both to right and left of an arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I have the following code where I would like to add labels to both left and right of the edge. How to do it?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
n1/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=black!5, very thick, minimum size=1mm},
]
%Nodes
\node[n1]    (Susceptible)                              {p};
\node[n1]    (Infectious)       [below=of Susceptible] {q};


%Lines
\draw[->, very thick] (Susceptible.south)  to node[right] {$a$} node[left] {$b$} (Infectious.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The image looks like: [image: this]
Here letter b is slightly below letter a, how to fix this?

Comment: Use `mid left` and `mid right`. (Or `base` instead of `mid`.) Alternatively make sure, they have the same depth/height (by adding `\vphantom{b}` to the `a` node's text).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what does \vphantom{b} do?

Comment: It adds vertical space that has the dimension is of the `b`. PGF/TikZ packs a node's content tightly in a box and puts the node's border around it (with a bit of passing according to `inner xsep` and `inner ysep`). The `b` is higher than the `a` and thus its node is also a bit higher. (Add `draw` to both to see that and that their vertical centers are actually aligned.) You either need to make both nodes have the same vertical dimensions relative to the baseline or use anchors/placement that are in a fixed distance to the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

PGF/TikZ packs a node's content tightly in a box and then puts that box in the center of the node with a bit of padding around it (the values of [`inner xsep` and `inner ysep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/inner:xsep)).

With `left` and `right` you implicitly specify the anchors `east` and `west` respectively which will be the anchors of placement.
As you can see in the [“definition” of the `rectangle` shape](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#sec-71.2), these anchors are vertically centered.

If we show the border of those nodes and connect their centers, you can see that they are on the same height:
[image]

You either need to use **anchors that are fixed relative to the baselines** (base west, base east, base, mid west, mid east, mid, text), i.e. here `mid right` (for anchor `mid east`) and `mid left` (for anchor `mid west`)

```
\draw[->, very thick]
  (Susceptible) to node[mid right] {$a$} node[mid left] {$b$} (Infectious);
```

which will look like
[image]

or you need to make the nodes have the **same vertical height**.

In this simple case, you could just add `\vphantom{b}`, i.e.

```
\draw[->, very thick]
  (Susceptible) to node[right] {$\vphantom{b}a$} node[left] {$b$} (Infectious);
```

which will add an invisible line that has the vertical dimensions of the `b`.

This will add the needed height to the box that PGF/TikZ uses:
[image]

There are other ways to **change the vertical dimensions** of a node's box, namely the keys `text height` (the part above the baseline) and `text depth` (the part below the baseline).

You coud say

```
\draw[->, very thick, text height=height("b")]
  (Susceptible) to node[right] (a) {$a$} node[left] (b) {$b$} (Infectious);
```

which will make both nodes have height of `b`, irregardless of their actual content. This is almost the same as `\vphantom{b}` however `\vphantom` is basically “*minimal* text height” (and depth).

---

If you have these cases very often where two nodes are placed side-by-side on a vertical line, you can define your own custom style that does a few of these things automatically, say

```
two edge nodes vertical/.style 2 args={
  edge node={node[mid left]{$#1$}node[mid right]{$#2$}}}
% or
two edge nodes vertical/.style 2 args={
  edge node={node[left]{$\vphantom{#2}#1$} node[right]{$\vphantom{#1}#2$}}}
```

and then you just do

```
\draw[->, very thick] (Susceptible) to[two edge nodes vertical={a}{b}] (Infectious);
```

---

Note that I've removed the explicit anchors north and south from your line because TikZ automatically connnects nodes only on their borders.

This also applies to other anchors/placements on non-vertical lines but unless the nodes are very different in dimensions this won't be as noticable.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  n1/.style={circle, draw=black!60, fill=black!5, very thick, minimum size=1mm},
  % mid anchors
  two edge nodes vertical/.style 2 args={
    edge node={node[mid left]{$#1$}          node[mid right]{$#2$}}},
  % vphantoms
  two edge nodes vertical/.style 2 args={
    edge node={node[left]{$\vphantom{#2}#1$} node[right]{$\vphantom{#1}#2$}}}
]
%Nodes
\node[n1] (Susceptible)                        {p};
\node[n1] (Infectious)  [below=of Susceptible] {q};

%Lines
\draw[->, very thick] (Susceptible) to[two edge nodes vertical={a}{b}] (Infectious);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a bit related to why the `tikz-cd` package uses its own `asymmetrical rectangle` which could have been used here, too. (The shape has their `west` and `east` anchors where the original shape has their mid anchors but the library adds a key that allows one to change the distance bitween base and mid.)