# Aligning labels on an axis placed with node[below]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,yscale=2,xscale=1.5]
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (0, 0) grid (2.5,1.5);
\draw[->] (0,0)--(2.5,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{};
\node[left] (O) at (0,0) {$0$};
\node[left] (1) at (0,1) {$1$};

\coordinate (a) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1.5,1);
%
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0)--(a) node {};
\draw[ultra thick] (a)--(b) node {};
\draw[ultra thick] (b)--(2.5,1) node {};

\draw[dashed] (1.5,0) -- (1.5,1) node {};

\node[below] () at (1,0) {$a$};
\node[below] () at (1.5,0) {$b$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

that outputs:
[image]

Tha labels `a` and `b` on the x axis are not correctly aligned (vertically).

Is there any way to align them?

Comment: Quick fix: Add `\vphantom{b}` to the `a` node: `{$a\vphantom{b}$}`. If you need this often, just set their `text height=height("$b$")`. Similar: [A661932](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661932) but I'm sure there a few hundred more. Basically, the nodes are tightly around the text (+ `inner sep`). They don't consider any baseline. You will need to use their `base` or `mid` anchors when placing them or make them have the same height.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Qrrbrbirlbel's comment. However here is another option: a `\strut`, that creates a vertical space with the needed height and depth but no horizontal space.

That said, I reduced your code a bit:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,yscale=2,xscale=1.5]
\coordinate (a) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1.5,1);
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (0,0) grid (2.5,1.5);
\draw[->] (0,1) node[left]{$1$} -- (0,0) node[left] {$0$} -- (a) node[below]{\strut$a$} -- (2.5,0) node[below]{\strut$x$};
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (a) -- (b) -- (2.5,1);
\draw[dashed] (1.5,0) node[below] {\strut$b$} -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]